# app.config vs. appsettings.json in WPF .NET Framework app

Tags: .net, configuration-management

I am building a .NET Framework WPF application, however, I want to use [IConfigurationBuilder](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.configuration.iconfigurationbuilder?view=dotnet-plat-ext-7.0), which is a part of the newer (.NET Core and up) Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration namespace. My understanding is that .NET Framework apps traditionally use the app.config file in conjunction with [ConfigurationManager](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.configuration.configurationmanager?view=dotnet-plat-ext-7.0) class.

Unfortunately, I have to use .NET Framework. Despite this, I would strongly prefer IConfigurationBuilder as a) this is the more modern approach, b) it meshes well with adding services/DI (through Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting and the [Host](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.hosting.host?view=dotnet-plat-ext-7.0) class), and c) it appears easier in numerous aspects than working with the older app.config setup, particularly when it comes to managing configurations for different environments.

I think I could keep app.config and still integrate with my Host setup by using the Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Xml NuGet (which has several [AddXmlFile](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.configuration.xmlconfigurationextensions?view=dotnet-plat-ext-7.0) methods). I believe I could also just delete the app.config (and Settings.settings) and add an appsettings.json.

My question is: can I expect any issues with choosing appsettings.json over app.config in a .NET Framework application? I am curious if others have done this, and if so, why they did this. I welcome any advice or insight related to this.

Comment: How exactly do you intend to use `ConfigurationBuilder`or `IConfigurationBuilder` in your .Net Fw application? As you said, those classes are not part of the classic .NET framework - are you thinking of to backporting them?

Comment: The NuGet package for those is supported in .NET Framework since 4.6.2 (and .NET Standard 2.0);  so as long as you are targeting a newer version of Framework 4.x, preferably 4.8 which is still in support (4.6.2 is obsolete and out-of-support), then you should be fine:  https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Json/#supportedframeworks-body-tab

Comment: `.exe.config` is still used for [purposes unrelated to your application's custom settings/config](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/configure-apps/file-schema/). The CLR will automatically try to locate `MyProgram.exe.config` for these, and will expect the file to match the XML configuration schema.    On the other hand, `appSettings.json` is far more loosely defined, and more importantly is unrelated to any .NET CLR feature, so it cannot replace exe.config for anything but your own custom config).

Comment: @BenCottrell Thank you for confirming about compatibility of the NuGet packages (relatively new developer here, so still figuring out where I can find out the answers to all my questions!). Regarding the `.exe.config` it's good to know about it. I see that when I do not have an `app.config`, but rather an `appsettings.json`, building the project results in the `.exe.config` but `app.config` is not re-generated. Which is what I think you are saying and is ideal for my purposes - I ultimately would like to use `appsettings.json` and the associated, newer, libraries.

Comment: At some point, I am expecting to update the project itself to be .NET 6, but confirming that the NuGet (and the Framework overall) is compatible with `appsettings.json` and associated, newer, libraries, gives me more confidence about the application. Thank you @BenCottrell!